# How to cross-import modules in subdirectory so they work as sub-module and as a stand-alone?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

I have a Python module that normally works as a stand-alone.

```
file1.py
file2.py
file3.py
```

However, I also want it to be part of a different project, in which the module is placed in a separate subdirectory.

```
__init.py__
build.py
└── compiler
    └── __init__.py
    └── file1.py
    └── file2.py
    └── file3.py
```

Since the module scripts use plenty of cross-imports, this is not possible. Once placed in a subdirectory, the imports no longer find the respective files because it looks in the top directory only.

To remedy the problem, I tried various things. I appended the subdirectory as an additional path in the top-most `build.py` script.

```
sys.path.append('compiler')
```

It did not solve the problem. Cross-imports are still not working.

I also tried relative imports but that breaks the stand-alone version of the module. So, I tried exception handling to catch them

```
try:
    from file1 import TestClass
except ImportError:
    from .file1 import TestClass
```

That did not work either and resulted, despite my best efforts in `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` errors.

I also tried all sorts of variations of these things, but none of it worked.

I know it has to be possible to do something like this and I am surprised that this is so hard to do. My Internet searches all came back with the same suggestions—the ones I outlined above, none of which worked in my case, particularly because they do not take into account the ability to run code as a stand-alone and as a sub-module.

I can't be the first person trying to write a module that can be used as a stand-alone package or as a sub-module in other projects. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why can't you do `from .file1 import TestClass`?

Comment: This does not work in the standalone version because there is no parent, causing a `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` error. :(

Comment: Add a guard `if __name__ != '__main__': from .file1 import TestClass`

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports, as the error tells you, require a parent package.  Think of `.file1` as shorthand for `<this_module>.file1`.  If there is no `<this_module>`, you can't ask it for `file1`.  In order to properly use relative imports you'll have to make a wrapper project to contain the shared module so it can be properly namespaced.

So your standalone module will instead look like this, matching the consumer:

```
__init.py__
standalone.py
└── compiler
    └── __init__.py
    └── file1.py
    └── file2.py
    └── file3.py
```

The other option is to make your shared module truly installable with a `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml` or whatever your favorite method is.  Then you install it in the consuming project instead of directly including it.